# multiple datasource in spring boot for mysql and mongo

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

i am new to spring boot. My requirement is to use both mysql and mongo database. For some transaction related operation i will use mysql and for fetching purpose i will store/retrieve the data to mongo. I went through a lots of exampe, now i am completely confused. i want some structure like JPArepository, where i can use the inbuilt methods .e.g

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends MongoRepository<Customer, String> {}
```

and

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> { }
```

Just mention the connection and that will point to the right database. i have lots of tables in both the database. A sample example will also be helpful how to write queries using the different connections.

Comment: you mean both datasource to use the same Customer entity and you want to have different repository in each database such as MongoCustomerRepository and MySQLCustomerRepository right?

Comment: No two different repository to manage different tables. E.g. we will have customer, payment details, all private data on mysql. And other data like coomon details / searchable data will be put to mongo cluster.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example
[@EnableJpaRepositories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/config/EnableJpaRepositories.html)

- using basePackages for specifying the packages to scan for annotated components.
- using em.setPackagesToScan for set whether to use Spring-based scanning for entity classes in the classpath.

Let's create mysql and mongo config class following code.

For MySQL

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"yourpackage.mysql.repositories"},
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "mysqlEntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "mysqlTransactionManager")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class mysqlConfig {

@Bean(name = "mysqlEntityManagerFactory")
@Primary
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(dataSourceWrite());
    em.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"yourpackage.mysql.entities"});
    em.setPersistenceUnitName("trueid");
    JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

    return em;
}

@Bean(name = "dataSourceMysql",destroyMethod = "close")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    ...
    return dataSource;
}


@Bean(name = "mysqlTransactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier(value = "entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);

    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean(name = "mysqlExceptionTranslation")
public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
}

Properties additionalProperties() {

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", ...);
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
    return properties;
}


}
```

For Mongo

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"yourpackage.mongo.repositories"},
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "mongoEntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "mongoTransactionManager")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class mongoConfig {

@Bean(name = "mongoEntityManagerFactory")
@Primary
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(dataSourceWrite());
    em.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"yourpackage.mongo.entities"});
    em.setPersistenceUnitName("trueid");
    JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

    return em;
}

@Bean(name = "dataSourceMongo",destroyMethod = "close")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    ...
    return dataSource;
}


@Bean(name = "mongoTransactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier(value = "mongoEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);

    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean(name = "mongoExceptionTranslation")
public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
}

Properties additionalProperties() {

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", ...);
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
    return properties;
}


}
```

Entities and Repositories class

- You can manage different package as your detail the customer, payment details, all private data class should put to "yourpackage.mysql.entities" and other data class like coomon details / searchable data will be put to "yourpackage.mongo.entities"

I hope this helps

Comment: mongo.datasource.url=mongodb://localhost:27017/test


# mysql DB - 
mysql.datasource.uri=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
mysql.datasource.username=root
mysql.datasource.password=root
mysql.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: What will be the valus for hibernate.dialect. I have my application properties as above.

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html
for MySQL => org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect 

for MongoDB => using Hibernate OGM http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/ogm/4.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#ogm-mongodb-annotation-configuration

Comment: the example for mongodb config https://stackoverflow.com/a/33393509/2090568